# Rails Fullcalendar show only current employee events

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, fullcalendar

I would like the arshaw.com/fullcalendar to show only events for the current user.

The code for Fullcalendar selects the date with this statement:

```
   eventSources: [{
  url: '/events',
}],
```

The Events table has employee_id in it.  How do you configure a url so it gets only the json records for a certain employee?

```
url: '/events?employee_id='2'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `/events.json?employee_id=2`?

Comment: I tried - but, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I do this on my server side. I wrote a query that returns only tasks that have `owner_id` the same as `current_user.id`. Even if you decide to do this on the client-side, you should still have server-side validation to check whether the user logged in really has `employee_id` that fullcalendar submitted.